# How to work with the jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, fadein, slidedown

I have a HTML structure like this:-

```
<article id="a_post" class="a_post">
<div id="thumbnail">
<img id="shine" src="wp-content/themes/dabanggknight/images/play.png"/>
</div>
<div id="instant_video" class="instant_video">
<span class="close"></span>
    // Some content here
</div>
</article>    
<article id="a_post" class="a_post">
<div id="thumbnail">
<img id="shine" src="wp-content/themes/dabanggknight/images/play.png"/>
</div>
<div id="instant_video" class="instant_video">
<span class="close"></span>
    // Some content here
</div>
</article>
```

In the above HTML, `<div id="instant_video" class="instant_video">
    <span class="close"></span>
        // Some content here
    </div>` has a css of `display:none;`.
All I want to do is when someone clicks on  `<img id="shine" src="wp-content/themes/dabanggknight/images/play.png"/>` I want to slide down the div with the id of instant_video whose display is set to none in css.

Then when someone clicks on the span with the class of close, it fades out that particular div again.

But I'm having a severe problem with the jQuery selectors because I'm really amateur with it.

The code that I'm using slides in all the hidden divs with the id of `instant_video` and that's where the problem persists.

All I want to do is slide down only the div inside the article tag which contains the image I clicked on.

The code that I'm currently using is as follows:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('img#shine').click(function() {
        jQuery('.instant_video').slideDown('fast')
    }); 
});
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.close').click(function() {
        jQuery('.instant_video').fadeOut('slow')
    }); 
});
```

Comment: first - use `$` instead `jQuery` - just shorter, next - use `$(document).ready(function()...`only once per page

Comment: my advice: don't use the same name for a class and id, and NEVER give the same id to more than 1 element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('.a_post img').click(function() {
      $(this).closest('.a_post').find('.instant_video').slideDown('fast')
   });

   $('.close').click(function() {
      $(this).closest('.instant_video').fadeOut('slow')
   });
});
```

no need to have `$(document).ready` twice

also `id` tags must always be unique

because you have lot of `instant_video` you should use `closest` to get the one that is related to the `img` you clicked

Answer (score 5):

First off, it is not permitted to have more than one element with any given `id`. `id` attributes have to be unique in the document.

The solution to your problem is to give your `img` elements a `class` attribute rather than an `id`, then to use the jQuery's traversal methods (`closest and` `find` in this case) to get the relevant element.

So, assuming that your `img` elements have the class `shine`, you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img.shine').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('article').find('.instant_video').slideDown('fast');
    });
    $('span.close').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.instant_video').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind that IDs are unique. You can't have two elements with the same ID on one page!

However, try something like this:
Assign a class to the img `#shine` instead of an id:

`<img class="shine" src="wp-content/themes/dabanggknight/images/play.png"/>`

Then use this code:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('img.shine').on('click', function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('.a_post').find('.instant_video').slideDown('fast');
    });

    jQuery('.close').on('click', function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('.a_post').find('.instant_video').fadeOut('slow');
    }); 
});​
```

(or shorter, try this:)

```
$(function(){
    $('img.shine').on('click', function(){
        $(this).closest('.a_post').find('.instant_video').slideDown('fast');
    });

    $('.close').on('click', function(){
        $(this).closest('.a_post').find('.instant_video').fadeOut('slow');
    }); 
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like;

```
$('#shine').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.a_post').find('.instant_video').slideDown('fast');
});
$('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.instant_video').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/eR2Xw/1/)*** is a working Live Demo.

Answer (score -1):

ids must be unique to a page , you are selecting by class ie

```
jQuery('.instant_video')
```

selecting by  id is like this

```
jQuery('#instant_video')
```

Comment: you are right,but you have just answered the title of the questions, not the question itself